# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'random' when running python in Atom

Tags: python, module, atom-editor

my code is:

```
import random
import numpy

z = numpy.zeros(5)
print(z)
d = random.random()
```

and the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wjxiz/Documents/et5/bigdata/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    d = random.random()
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'random'
```

I hava already installed "scripts" to run scripts in atom. 
I installed my python3 by Homebrew and my path is:

```
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin /Library/TeX/texbin
```

when I type which python3 and which python in terminal:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python
```

I can run normal code correctly but when I import random, problem occurs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most likely you have named one of your files `random.py`, so Atom imports that, instead of the python random module

Comment: Make sure you delete your local random.pyc in addition to random.py

Comment: everything ingenious is simple! :D

Answer (score 0):

Do not have python filenames with random.py or numpy.py while creating your python file.